# Can you achieve a non-square look with tiles or a similar technique?

Tags: tiles, level-design

Just to explain the kind of look that is refered to in the question, it is apparent in the game [Toejam and Earl 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzzOQy4HNzA).

[image: Toejam and Earl 2]

Not asking how this was made but would like to know how you could efficiently blit a level design that isn't made or doesn't appear to look like easily identifiable square tiles. Another example for a "non-blocky" world would be worms but that looked more like a bitmap which sounds like it would require a lot of memory and could potentially limit the game world size.

Comment: I think the answer is "yes, you can" but it's always going to take more X where X is ram, textures, processing, or something else. e.g. you can make "corner" sprites where the corner tile on a boundary with another tile type has a different look (say, diagonal split) so it doesn't *look* square, but it still is.

Comment: But this looks like an arbitrary curve?

Answer (score 2):

The modern way to achieve this effect are polygonial "tiles", (they don't really have a name, but Unity calls them Smart tiles, more in [this](https://youtu.be/muRhea-JaIM) video).

Basically, instead of using squares, you create a polygon and fill it with a repeatable image. Then you can define on which parts of this polygon you want to have a different tileset covering the top, like a grass layer.